# How To construct a object in JS which corresponds to an object in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, api, web

I use .Net web API and i want to get the structure of my objects in C# and send it to the front so it can construct object exactly like the back.

But i don't know how to get the exact structure of my objects in C# ( the structure and the name of the attributes )

for example an object will be this kind of object

```
public class{
  public int a;
  private string b;
  private anAnotherObject c;
  private List<otherObjects> d;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to only have private member variables?

Comment: it's an example of objects, members could be private or public does't matter here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First why you are having `private` members?

Let's say if they are public. Then you can use Javascript Serializer to serialize you object to json and send it to html or `View`.

Using ajax call you can send json that will be received as object on ur action `method`

```
  $.ajax({url:url,
          data:{j:dataModelOnJson},...})
```

})

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following way

Below is my class

```
  public class MyVM
    {
        public int ID {get;set;}
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my action here my action is MVC controller action this can be your api action. Which is expecting class object here.

```
 public ActionResult Create(MyVM createVM)
{
///Create Entry
}
```

Now when you make call using jquery you can do it like

CreateEntry will be called on your button click event. and there is variable called CreateModel which is replica of you class and you are passing value from js by getting value from textboxes.

```
function CreateEntry()
{
var _id = $("#txtId").val();
var _Name = $("#txtName").val();
var CreateModel = {
           ID : _id,
       Name  : _Name
        }
var url=""MyAPI/Create"
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            headers: headers,
            url: url,
            data: {
                createVM: CreateModel //Action Parameter name and variable which will map with class value.
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Save Success");
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                ErrorRosterMessage();
            }
        });
}
```

This will automatically map with your action class name and its value.

Comment: yeah it works like that but i have to create a model for all the objects i have in the back. 

Is there a method to get the actual format of an object in c# ? like 

`public class MyVM
    {
        public int ID {get;set;}
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public MyObject o {get; set;}
        public int other {get; set; }
    }

MyVM.getProperties();
`
will return a list => int , string, MyObject {int , st